# Passing parameters from programatically-built buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a little PyQt5 application that will do some work on a directory of files for me. I need to build a QGridLayout to hold the buttons. Naturally, the contents are subject to change, so I'm building the buttons by looping through a list of simple objects (path, filename, etc.).

My question is this: how do I pass an identifying parameter from the button's "on_click" action when they're built from a loop? I don't care too much what I return from the click - I can find the matching file object one way or another.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, \
    QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

from DirListing import Listing


class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Grid Test'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.createGridLayout()

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

        self.show()

    def createGridLayout(self):
        self.horizontalGroupBox = QGroupBox("Grid")
        layout = QGridLayout()

        counter = 0

        for obj in Listing:

            button = QPushButton(obj.filename)
            button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
            layout.addWidget(button, counter, 0)

            counter = counter + 1

        self.horizontalGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print("Halp!")

    def lower(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = App()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The fun part is just the little loop that begins with "for obj in Listing" - that's my loop of file objects. I use a simple counter to go down one row in the GridLayout for each button. But I can't figure out how to pass a unique parameter out of the click function.

Comment: Could you explain yourself better, do you want to pass a new parameter to on_click?

Comment: I want to pass a parameter that identifies the object linked to the button. The display name on the button is the filename. I want a parameter that says "the user clicked the button with name <x>" (or some equivalent.) Then I'll know which file object to continue working with. Maybe I'm making this too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to perform this task, I will list some:

1. Use `sender()` which is a function that returns the object that emits the signal and some attribute of the widget, in the case of `QPushButton` you can use the text that is shown

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        for i in range(10):
            button = QPushButton("{}".format(i), self)
            self.layout().addWidget(button)
            button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print("button-{}".format(self.sender().text()))
```

2. Using `objectName()` where each widget is given a particular name

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        for i in range(10):
            button = QPushButton("{}".format(i), self)
            self.layout().addWidget(button)
            button.setObjectName("button-{}".format(i))
            button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print(self.sender().objectName())
```

3. Using lambda functions

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        for i in range(10):
            button = QPushButton("{}".format(i), self)
            self.layout().addWidget(button)
            button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, i=i: self.on_click(i))

    def on_click(self, i):
        print("button-{}".format(i))
```

4. For buttons you can use `QButtonGroup`

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        group = QButtonGroup(self)
        for i in range(10):
            button = QPushButton("{}".format(i), self)
            self.layout().addWidget(button)
            group.addButton(button, i)
        group.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.on_click)
        group.buttonClicked.connect(self.on_click2)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_click(self, i):
        print("button-{}".format(i))

    def on_click2(self, btn):
        print("2button-{}".format(btn.text()))
```

5. Using `functools.partial`

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        for i in range(10):
            button = QPushButton("{}".format(i), self)
            self.layout().addWidget(button)
            import functools
            button.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.on_click, i))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self, i):
        print("button-{}".format(i))
```

Comment: A little more help please... can you show me how to slot your code into my original? Mine is cobbled together from various tutorials. I'm still trying to understand how all these gears fit together. Thanks.

Comment: @Dito Share me a code that can be executed, yours looks like a pseudocode, through github or gist and then I will help you with what you want.

Comment: @Dito Also which of the options do you want?

Comment: Give me a while to get it running again (I broke it while testing). I'll post it all as you asked. Thanks in advance for your help and patience. I don't have a preference as to which method.

Comment: @Dito If you learn to version your software you will always have a backup of your modifications, and github helps you in this, I recommend you try it. Notify me when you have a code that I can execute. :P

Comment: I have Mercurial installed but hadn't yet set it up for this "testing" directory. Lesson learned.

Comment: Here's the gist entry for what I've created. The "DirListing.py" file is a dummy file - I loaded the list by hand because I couldn't send the convoluted logic that scans directories and finds real files.

https://gist.github.com/bundito/99f8aa7904bb71260c68da3f481874ca

I don't care which version we use... whichever you think is simplest to understand and reuse in other places.

Comment: There is the [code](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/3d200020db4af413282dc8a96eb732b5). Please do not forget to mark my answer as correct.